# Predicting package delivery schedules

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

- A delivery man has N packages to deliver, already sorted.
- He starts the route at `start_time`, he works until `end_time`.
- I have historical data of his delivery schedules.
- There's no geographic information between each drop point.

How can I predict the delivery times for each package?

I've tried the following approaches, which don't seem to solve this appropriately:

1. **Machine learning**: perfect for classifying the input into classes, which doesn't apply for this scenario. I even did the ML Coursera course in 2 weeks, just to see if any topics were suitable.
2. **Kalman filter**: or other DSP-related algorithms focus too much on real-time, short-spanned predictions, which is not the case. No way of leveraging historical data.
3. **Markov chains**: great for guessing the present state, not so much for a future value.
4. **Mathematical model**: I could come up with a mathematical model (gaussian curves?) which denotes the time it takes between package delivery, depending on hour of day. Based on that, predict the delivery times.

Which topics should I focus on?

A few notes on the historical data:

- I have everything from start times, end times, and delivery times for each package. I also have all the GPS data for those routes, if that helps.
- The drop-off places should be considered random, so the delivery times look pretty random themselves.
- There's a slow-down on lunch time.

Comment: What does the historical data look like?

Comment: @DanPichelman check edited answer

Comment: (aside - there is some discussion in [chat] (The Whiteboard) about this if you want to poke in there)

Comment: Clarify your input(s) and expected output(s) very precisely pls.